# Get a unicode from python's str byte sequence

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an old django app which was saving UTF-8 strings in the database in a way that made some look like invalid utf8 when I try to fetch them in Ruby.

Strings before saving were of type `str` in python, but when fetched from the database django was giving me a proper `unicode` string. When I fetch same record in rails I get a byte sequence that is identical to python's `str` string and ruby complains that it's an invalid byte sequence.

Example: tested string was a single emoji:

- before save in Django - `str` type, sequence: `[237, 160, 189, 237, 180, 165]`
- fetched from db in Django - `unicode` type, sequence `[55357, 56613]`
- fetched from db in Rails - sequence `[237, 160, 189, 237, 180, 165]`

Is there a way to convert that byte sequence in Ruby to a proper utf8 string?

Answer (score 2):

I can't solve your problem but I can explain that byte sequence. What you have is UTF-8 encoded UTF-16.

Both, `237, 160, 189` and `237, 180, 165` are 3-byte UTF-8 sequences:

- `1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx` (the `x`'s are the relevant bits)

... which translate to codepoints `55357` and `56613` respectively: (or `0xD83D` and `0xDD25` in hex)

```
[237, 160, 189, 237, 180, 165].map { |b| b.to_s(2) }
#=> ["11101101", "10100000", "10111101", "11101101", "10110100", "10100101"]
#         ^^^^      ^^^^^^      ^^^^^^        ^^^^      ^^^^^^      ^^^^^^

[0b1101_100000_111101, 0b1101_110100_100101]
#=> [55357, 56613]
```

Unfortunately, these codepoints are *invalid* in UTF-8. That's because they are actually UTF-16 bytes:

```
[55357, 56613].pack('S>2').encode('utf-8', 'utf-16be')
#=> ""
```