# How to get UTF-16 (decimal) in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-16

I have Unicode Code Point of an emoticon represented as **U+1F498**:

```
emoticon = u'\U0001f498'
```

I would like to get utf-16 decimal groups of this character, which according to [this website](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f498/index.htm) are `55357` and `56472`.

I tried to do `print emoticon.encode("utf16")` but did not help me at all because it gives some other characters.

Also, trying to decode from UTF-8 before encode it to UTF-16 as follow `print str(int("0001F498", 16)).decode("utf-8").encode("utf16")` does not help either.

How do I correctly get the utf-16 decimal groups of a unicode character?

Comment: There are essentially 2 separate questions here: How to convert a hex string to a unicode character (or code point), and how to turn a unicode character into utf-16 decimal groups. Would you mind if we remove the first question, and assume that the input is a unicode character or code point, rather than a hex string?

Comment: Look, meanwhile I found this thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145161/get-a-unicode-from-pythons-str-byte-sequence where the answer is showing how to do exactly the opposite. But it is a bit hard get the idea. How to get these two numbers ? And yes, please, any help would be appreciated ! Thank you in advance !

Comment: Just a suggestion: Upgrade to Python 3 right now. A few things changed, in particular in the area of strings, and it's little use learning a language that's obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

You can [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) the character with the `utf-16` encoding, and then convert every 2 bytes of the encoded data to integers with [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) (or [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) in python 2).

### Python 3

```
def utf16_decimals(char, chunk_size=2):
    # encode the character as big-endian utf-16
    encoded_char = char.encode('utf-16-be')

    # convert every `chunk_size` bytes to an integer
    decimals = []
    for i in range(0, len(encoded_char), chunk_size):
        chunk = encoded_char[i:i+chunk_size]
        decimals.append(int.from_bytes(chunk, 'big'))

    return decimals
```

### Python 2 + Python 3

```
import struct

def utf16_decimals(char):
    # encode the character as big-endian utf-16
    encoded_char = char.encode('utf-16-be')

    # convert every 2 bytes to an integer
    decimals = []
    for i in range(0, len(encoded_char), 2):
        chunk = encoded_char[i:i+2]
        decimals.append(struct.unpack('>H', chunk)[0])

    return decimals
```

Result:

```
>>> utf16_decimals(u'\U0001f498')
[55357, 56472]
```

Comment: Thank you very, very, very much!

Answer (score 0):

In a Python 2 "narrow" build, it is as simple as:

```
>>> emoticon = u'\U0001f498'
>>> map(ord,emoticon)
[55357, 56472]
```

This works in Python 2 (narrow and wide builds) and Python 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import struct

emoticon = u'\U0001f498'
print(struct.unpack('<2H',emoticon.encode('utf-16le')))
```

Output:

```
(55357, 56472)
```

This is a more general solution that prints the UTF-16 code points for any length of string:

```
from __future__ import print_function,division
import struct

def utf16words(s):
    encoded = s.encode('utf-16le')
    num_words = len(encoded) // 2
    return struct.unpack('<{}H'.format(num_words),encoded)

emoticon = u'ABC\U0001f498'
print(utf16words(emoticon))
```

Output:

```
(65, 66, 67, 55357, 56472)
```